# Yocto How to stop cmake to look in a native sysroot path for linking?

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, yocto

I'm trying to add dlib python module into my image so far this is the recipe i'm working on...

```
# python3-dlib_19.21.1.bb
SUMMARY = "A toolkit for making real world machine learning and data analysis applications"
HOMEPAGE = "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dlib"
PYPI_PACKAGE = "dlib"
LICENSE = "Boost-Software"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "1e7e357d7d54e86267ef60f606cb40e1"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://dlib/LICENSE.txt;md5=2c7a3fa82e66676005cd4ee2608fd7d2 \
                    file://dlib/external/libpng/LICENSE;md5=243135ddedf702158f9170807cbcfb66 \
                    file://dlib/external/pybind11/LICENSE;md5=beb87117af69fd10fbf9fb14c22a2e62 \
                    file://python_examples/LICENSE_FOR_EXAMPLE_PROGRAMS.txt;md5=064f53ab40ea2b6a4bba1324149e4fde \
"
DEPENDS = "cmake-native"

inherit  pypi setuptools3
```

but when do_compile() ran i got the following error message:

```
| [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_dlib_pybind11.dir/src/line.cpp.o
| [100%] Linking CXX shared module build_dunfell/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-dlib/19.21.1-r0/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/_dlib_pybind11.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
| build_dunfell/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-dlib/19.21.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/8.3.0/ld: build_dunfell/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-dlib/19.21.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/libsqlite3.so: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
| collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
| CMakeFiles/_dlib_pybind11.dir/build.make:445: recipe for target 'build_dunfell/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-dlib/19.21.1-r0/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/_dlib_pybind11.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so' failed
| make[2]: *** [build_dunfell/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-dlib/19.21.1-r0/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/_dlib_pybind11.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so] Error 1
| CMakeFiles/Makefile2:116: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/_dlib_pybind11.dir/all' failed
| make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/_dlib_pybind11.dir/all] Error 2
| Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
| make: *** [all] Error 2
| Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "build_dunfell/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-dlib/19.21.1-r0/dlib-19.21.1/setup.py", line 223, in <module>
|     setup(
|   File "build_dunfell/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-dlib/19.21.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
|     return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
|   File "build_dunfell/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-dlib/19.21.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
|     dist.run_commands()
|   File "build_dunfell/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-dlib/19.21.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
|     self.run_command(cmd)
|   File "build_dunfell/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-dlib/19.21.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
|     cmd_obj.run()
|   File "build_dunfell/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-dlib/19.21.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
|     self.run_command(cmd_name)
|   File "build_dunfell/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-dlib/19.21.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
|     self.distribution.run_command(command)
|   File "build_dunfell/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-dlib/19.21.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
|     cmd_obj.run()
|   File "build_dunfell/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-dlib/19.21.1-r0/dlib-19.21.1/setup.py", line 135, in run
|     self.build_extension(ext)
|   File "build_dunfell/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-dlib/19.21.1-r0/dlib-19.21.1/setup.py", line 175, in build_extension
|     subprocess.check_call(cmake_build, cwd=build_folder)
|   File "build_dunfell/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-dlib/19.21.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
|     raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
| subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '-j8']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
|
```

it looks like the problem occurs when cmake is trying to link the shared object **_dlib_pybind11.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so**. Linker complains with the following error

```
 adding symbols: file in wrong format
```

i think the linker is mixing target objects with native ones, but i'm not used to cmake so i don't know how to stop it to use the path of recipe-sysroot-native and use my target sysroot, if i remove cmake-native and use only DEPENDS="cmake", setup.py fails because it can not find cmake at all...

hope you can help me or give me any idea that i can try.

BR,

## Update 1

just as @Nayfe pointed out dlib/setup.py has an [--set](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/1516cf31c3ab05e6c62bbea2a1c7310b07ca1cfb/setup.py#L29) option to pass CMAKE config variables, below is a recipe that already worked for me, i can import dlib without problems.

```
SUMMARY = "A toolkit for making real world machine learning and data analysis applications"
HOMEPAGE = "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dlib"
PYPI_PACKAGE = "dlib"
LICENSE = "Boost-Software"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "1e7e357d7d54e86267ef60f606cb40e1"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://dlib/LICENSE.txt;md5=2c7a3fa82e66676005cd4ee2608fd7d2 \
                    file://dlib/external/libpng/LICENSE;md5=243135ddedf702158f9170807cbcfb66 \
                    file://dlib/external/pybind11/LICENSE;md5=beb87117af69fd10fbf9fb14c22a2e62 \
                    file://python_examples/LICENSE_FOR_EXAMPLE_PROGRAMS.txt;md5=064f53ab40ea2b6a4bba1324149e4fde \
"
DEPENDS = "sqlite3 "

inherit pypi cmake setuptools3
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "already-stripped"                                                                            

DISTUTILS_BUILD_ARGS_append = " \
      --set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${WORKDIR}/toolchain.cmake \
"
```

Comment: I suspect you should remove DEPENDS and add cmake to inherit, IMO.

Comment: thanks @SergeiNikulov, i tried your suggestion...
`inherit pypi cmake setuptools3` i left the bbclass pypi before cmake because i want to use the meta-python recipe convention and left setuptools3 after, so cmake can be used by setup.py, although this change i keep seeing the same error
`Linking CXX shared module build_dunfell/.../_dlib_pybind11.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
build_dunfell/.../recipe-sysroot-native/.../libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/8.3.0/ld: build_dunfell/.../recipe-sysroot-native/.../libsqlite3.so: error adding symbols: file in wrong format`

Comment: I'm also struggling with dlib. Compiling only C++ part is easy (just inherit cmake without setuptools3, but to add python wrappers, it gets harder. There are two ways to build it, using setuptools3 and injecting cmake missing variables (those declared by cmake.bbclass) or using only cmake to compile dlib tools/python folder, but it fails for now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe recipe can be optimized but the following works

- python3-dlib_19.21.bb

```
SUMMARY = "A toolkit for making real world machine learning and data analysis applications"
HOMEPAGE = "http://dlib.net/"
SECTION = "devel/python"
LICENSE = "BSL-1.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://dlib/LICENSE.txt;md5=2c7a3fa82e66676005cd4ee2608fd7d2"              

DEPENDS = "sqlite3"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/davisking/dlib"
SRCREV = "9117bd784328d9ac40ffa1f9cf487633a8a715d7"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

DISTUTILS_BUILD_ARGS_append = " \
      --set CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${prefix} \
      --set CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR:PATH=${@os.path.relpath(d.getVar('bindir'), d.getVar('prefix') + '/')} \
      --set CMAKE_INSTALL_SBINDIR:PATH=${@os.path.relpath(d.getVar('sbindir'), d.getVar('prefix') + '/')} \
      --set CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBEXECDIR:PATH=${@os.path.relpath(d.getVar('libexecdir'), d.getVar('prefix') + '/')} \
      --set CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR:PATH=${sysconfdir} \
      --set CMAKE_INSTALL_SHAREDSTATEDIR:PATH=${@os.path.relpath(d.getVar('sharedstatedir'), d.  getVar('prefix') + '/')} \
      --set CMAKE_INSTALL_LOCALSTATEDIR:PATH=${localstatedir} \
      --set CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR:PATH=${@os.path.relpath(d.getVar('libdir'), d.getVar('prefix') + '/')} \
      --set CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR:PATH=${@os.path.relpath(d.getVar('includedir'), d.getVar('prefix') + '/')} \
      --set CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR:PATH=${@os.path.relpath(d.getVar('datadir'), d.getVar('prefix') + '/')} \
      --set PYTHON_EXECUTABLE:PATH=${PYTHON} \
      --set Python_EXECUTABLE:PATH=${PYTHON} \
      --set Python3_EXECUTABLE:PATH=${PYTHON} \
      --set LIB_SUFFIX=${@d.getVar('baselib').replace('lib', '')} \
      --set CMAKE_INSTALL_SO_NO_EXE=0 \
      --set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${WORKDIR}/toolchain.cmake \
      --set CMAKE_NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED=1 \
      --set CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=${B} \
"

do_configure() {
    distutils3_do_configure
}

do_compile() {
    distutils3_do_compile
}

do_install() {
    distutils3_do_install
}

inherit cmake setuptools3 python3native

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "already-stripped"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "python3-core"
```

Comment: Hi @Nayfe, looks like i just need to point to the toolchain_file  and remove  dlib from DEPENDS. I will set your answer as correct thank you so much!! not sure how this recipe could be improved but i already asked in openembedded-devel group hope they can give some tips.