# where does python CMake Extension subdirectory build/lib.system name comes from?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I'm trying to find out how the name/directory **build/lib.system** is chosen/created within a distutils(setuptools) python build process...

when i build [dlib python module](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/99/2c/ef681c1c717ace11040f9e99fe22dafc843cdd6085eb6120e7ab2a5c662b/dlib-19.21.1.tar.gz) from source using `python3 setup.py build` i can see the following

````
build/
├── bdist.linux-aarch64
├── CMakeCache.txt
├── CMakeFiles
├── lib.linux-aarch64-3.8
└── temp.linux-aarch64-3.8```
````

reading at the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/extending/building.html) in **4.1** says:

> Depending on the system, the module file will end up in a subdirectory build/lib.system...

---

It's not clear to me where does **lib.${system}** comes from and if i can configure it using a [class extension](https://docs.python.org/3.8/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension) argument or it is a `-DCMAKE_VARIABLE`?

I'm using setuptools instead of distutils but for now it looks like the documentation in this subject is the same.

Please any help will be appreciated also, if anybody knows which is the path of the source code for class [Extension](https://docs.python.org/3.8/extending/building.html#) will be very helpfull.

thanks!!

Comment: `python setup.py build --build-lib=some/path`. The default value is composed out of `sys.platform`, `os.uname().machine` and `sys.version_info` on most platforms. The question is rather why you need to change it, or is it just a curiosity question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @hoefling thanks for the reply, well i'm actually struggling with a [yocto recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65822507/8033671), i'm trying to cross-compile dlib but it keeps trying to build it using host(native) environment instead of the target, so i thought that maybe if i know how does `lib.linux-x86_64-3.8` is created i could try to point at the correct build-sysroot.

Comment: I'm no expert in yocto (although I did some cross-compiling of Gentoo for aarch64 some years ago which yocto recipes syntax is deriving from), but since the build dir name has the wrong arch, you haven't configured the cross toolchain correctly.

Comment: Another thing is that you may have to fix `dlib`'s setup script. From a brief look, [this](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/1516cf31c3ab05e6c62bbea2a1c7310b07ca1cfb/setup.py#L171) may be the first spot to patch since the env vars are not passed to the child process: the line should be `subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder, env=os.environ.copy())`. Maybe there's more of this.

Comment: Last thing: [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/eeb701adc0fc29ba803fddf133d917ff45639a00/Lib/distutils/command/build.py#L73-L108) is the code that assembles the default build dir name, if you want to deeper understand where the name `lib/linux-x86_64-3.8` comes from.

Comment: Thanks @hoefling, looks like you where right i was missing the toolchain configuration, dlib/setup.py has an [--set](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/1516cf31c3ab05e6c62bbea2a1c7310b07ca1cfb/setup.py#L29) option so i just needed to set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE to point to the toolchain.cmake that cmake.bbclass creates, although i keep seeing the dir **lib.linux-x86_64-3.8** it works just fine but I'll be looking at your recommendations to clear this out.